# (Arduino) Can I skip multiple characters in a parseInt()?

Tags: c++, arduino

Pretty much what the title says. From the arduino website:

> **Syntax**
>
> Serial.parseInt()
>
> Serial.parseInt(char skipChar)
>
> **Parameters**
>
> skipChar: used to skip the indicated char in the search. Used for example to skip thousands divider.

Am I able to use a charmap or something similar to skip multiple characters?

Comment: Based on the provided prototypes for the function ,I have to go with no. You get to specify one or zero `chars`. There may be another function to do this, but more likely you'll have to do  the grunt work, possibly with the assistance of something from the <algorithm> library like `std::remove_if`, yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a very different method to get it working by using char arrays and not relying on timing. So far it has worked perfectly. I was using this to get my arduino to work as a temp monitor.

---

**How it communicates the temperatures**

PC > OpenHardwaremonitor > WMI > Batch Script (shown below) > COM Port > Arduino > LCD

This was the only way that I could get cpu temps correctly because it's so old

Batch code:

```
@echo off
mode COM3: baud=9600 data=8 >nul
wmic /namespace:\\root\openhardwaremonitor path sensor where "Identifier='/intelcpu/0/temperature/0' or Identifier='/nvidiagpu/0/temperature/0'" get Value /every:2|findstr [0-9]>COM3
```

Arduino code:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

bool sounded = false;
int cpu = 0;
int gpu = 0;

char invalids[3] = {10, 32, '\0'}; // line feed, space
boolean newData = false;
const byte numChars = 8;
char charMap[numChars];
char tempChars[numChars];

void setup() {
  pinMode(6, OUTPUT); // character intensity
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT); // buzzer
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT); // backlight
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  analogWrite(6, 100); // set intensity without POT
  analogWrite(10, 168); // ~3.3v
  analogReference(EXTERNAL);
  lcd.print("CPU:   ");
  lcd.print((char)223);
  lcd.print("C  AIR:");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("GPU:   ");
  lcd.print((char)223);
  lcd.print("C     ");
  lcd.print((char)223);
  lcd.print("F");
}

void loop() {
  recvWithoutWhitespace();
  if (newData == true) {
    parseData();
    lcd.setCursor(4, 0);
    lcd.print(cpu);
    lcd.setCursor(4, 1);
    lcd.print(gpu);
    int reading = analogRead(A0);
    float degreesF = (((reading * 3.3 / 1024 - 0.5) * 100) * 1.8) + 32.0;
    lcd.setCursor(11, 1);
    lcd.print((int)(degreesF+0.5));
    if(!sounded && (cpu > 75 || gpu > 85)) { // used for buzzer alarm
      tone(8, 500);
      delay(250);
      noTone(8);
      delay(250);
      tone(8, 500);
      delay(250);
      noTone(8);
      delay(250);
      tone(8, 500);
      delay(250);
      noTone(8);
      sounded = true;
    } else if(sounded && (cpu <= 75 && gpu <= 85)) {
      sounded = false;
    }
    newData = false;
  } 
}
void recvWithoutWhitespace() {
    static byte ndx = 0;
    static byte control = 0; // switch control variable
    char endMarker = 13; // ASCII code for carriage return
    char rc;
    char * check;

    while (Serial.available() > 0 && newData == false) {
        rc = Serial.read();
        check=strchr(invalids,rc); //checks if any spaces or line feeds get in

            if (check==NULL){ 
              if (rc != endMarker) {
                  charMap[ndx] = rc;
                  ndx++;
                 if (ndx >= numChars) {
                      ndx = numChars - 1;
                  }
             }
              else {
                switch(control) { // expect 4 CRs in format: (num)CRCR(num)CRCR
                  case 0:
                    control = 1; // skip first of 2 CRs
                    break;
                  case 1:
                    charMap[ndx] = 44; // put comma in place of CR between numbers as delimeter
                    ndx++;
                      if (ndx >= numChars) {
                        ndx = numChars - 1;
                      }
                    control = 2;
                    break;
                  case 2:
                    control = 3; // skip first of 2 CRs
                    break;
                  case 3:
                    charMap[ndx] = '\0'; // string terminator in place of last CR
                    ndx = 0;
                    control = 0;
                    newData = true;
                    break;
                }
              }
            }
    }
}
void parseData() {

    strcpy(tempChars, charMap); //strtok is destructive so copy string temporarily

    char * strtokIndx; // this is used by strtok() as an index

    strtokIndx = strtok(tempChars, ",");
    cpu = atoi(strtokIndx);     // convert cpu to an integer

    strtokIndx = strtok(NULL, ",");
    gpu = atoi(strtokIndx);     // convert gpu to an integer

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could read from Serial, but take digits only? And then parse string? Dirty example:

```
val = 0;
while (Serial.available() > 0) {
    int c = Serial.read();
    if (isDigit(c)) {
        val = val * 10 + c; // Thanks to @Danny_ds for this
    }
}
// Print *val*
```

Comment: You might as well convert to `int` while reading the bytes: `val = val * 10 + c;`. This way you don't need a buffer (but the int could overflow too of course).